# Read data from external devcie with serial port in Linux virtual machine on Windows 10 host

Tags: linux, python-2.7, serial-port, pyserial

I have a virtual machine with Linux (Lubuntu) on a Windows 10 Host. From my virtual machine i wanna connect with python to an external device via a serial port and read 1000 bytes. Therefore i am using the pyserial library.

On the Windows 10 host i just can use

```
if(serialHandler.isOpen()):
    serialHandler.read(1000)
```

and everything works perfect.

In the linux virtual machine this the same code gives me only 512 Bytes. So i tried to put the read call into a while loop. It Looks like

```
if(serialHandler.isOpen()):
    while serialHandler.inWaiting():
        serialHandler.read(1)
```

Anyways it gives me only 512 Bytes back. I tried several things without any success. I tried to delay the thread (sleep) to give the external device further time to process my read request. I tried to different codes with timeouts etc.

All gives me only 512 Bytes exactly. My assumption is that the root of this issue has to do with the serial buffer in Linux but i cannot resolve it. How can i get the second half of the 1000 bytes i need? Has it to do with the port mapping from the Linux virtual machine to the windows host? Any hints to solve the problem?

**UPDATE:**

LUBUNTU Linux System: Release 14.04, Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

In serial settings of the virtual machine i tried already "Host-Pipe" and "Host-Device" for configuring the COM Port on the Linux VM System.  Both doesn`t make a change.

Comment: What is your VM and how is it set up?

Comment: If you *"wanna"* get a answer, you *gotta* show your code.  Vote to close.